# Is "Parallelly" a good choice over 'In Parallel'?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Most online dictionary (M/W, Collins etc.) list this word: [**Parallelly**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parallelly) as:

> (adverb) *in a parallel manner*

Should we not use ***In Parallel*** instead? I did not find any [book](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22parallelly%22&sca_esv=8add31af34f47e86&biw=1848&bih=966&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn0-2OVEn3YymY4VwsXLp5i1h8-L_Jg%3A1706631460155&ei=JCG5Zc3-CO2s5NoP_eSG4Ac&ved=0ahUKEwjNoMfPwYWEAxVtFlkFHX2yAXwQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22parallelly%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIgwicGFyYWxsZWxseSIyBRAAGIAESJQLUOoHWIUJcAB4AJABAJgBfKAB6gKqAQMzLjG4AQPIAQD4AQGIBgE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) which uses "Parallelly" and is grammar or anthropology related. They are all technical or STEM books which I do not confide in as a good source of grammatically correct references.

Is *Parallelly* accurate / even idiomatic? Do native speakers consider using it instead of *In Parallel* as correct?

Example:

1. I went home and saw a huge mess in the middle of the dining area. I had to make dinner, or clean up house or do them *in parallel*.
2. I went home and saw a huge mess in the middle of the dining area. I had to make dinner, or clean up house or do them *parallelly*.

Comment: It's fine but it's a tonguetwister so in a parallel manner or in parallel are preferred. :) [This is my personal opinion.] In the main, words defined in dictionaries of that caliber are real words.

Comment: But the iNOW corpus contains 1071 instances of _parallelly_, against 30755 of _in parallel_. It's very rare.

Comment: “Is it _real_” is a tricky topic. “Is it a good choice” might be easier.

Comment: It might help to give a sentence you're considering using it in. You can use "in parallel" in contexts where "parallelly" would be odd: doing something "in parallel" means two or more people are proceeding through at the same time, without any literal mathematical concept of parallelism.